Code not executed from worker thread but rather from origin thread in MicroProfile EE 8 Applicaton
I have a Java EE 8 MicroProfile application I'm working on that is being deployed in Payara Server. I want to do some parallel processing on a XLSX file I'm receiving in a REST API. In order to parallelize the work, I'm using ManagedExecutorService (but have also tried with a non-EE newFixedThreadPool instance as well), create the required Callable instances I need and invoke them. The behavior I'm getting is weird since it seems that although the Callable seems to be invoked by the corresponding thread, the actual parallel work needed (that lives inside another ApplicationScoped bean I have) seems to run on the http pool.
I have to mention that all the related beans in the whole situation (from REST, to the last service) are ApplicationScoped except from a Singleton EJB which I have tried taking out of the equation to eliminate as a possibility but issue still persists.
My code looks a bit like this:
@ApplicationScoped
public class BusinessService {
  private @Inject RowConverter RowConverter;
  private @Resource ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;

  public void process(InputStream fileInputStream) {
    try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileInputStream)) {
      Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
      Iterator<Row> iterator = IteratorUtils.filteredIterator(sheet.rowIterator(), row -> row.getRowNum() > 0 && row.getCell("FOOBAR", Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL) != null);
    }
    Map<RequestValidity, List<EInvoiceRequest>> requests = getRequestsMap(IteratorUtils.toList(iterator));
  

    List<Callable<Stream<MyWrapperObj>>> callables = ListUtils.partition(rows, Math.max(300, rows.size() / 10)).stream()
      .map(partition -> new RowToMyWrapperObjCallable(partition, rowConverter))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return managedExecutorService.invokeAll(callables).stream()
      .flatMap(future -> {
        try {
          return future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          log.error("Error processing XLSX file", e);
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
          log.error("Error processing XLSX file", e);
        }
        throw new GenericException("Error processing commissions XLSX file", ErrorCode.FILE_PROCESSING_ERROR);
      }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> isRequestValid(r) ? RequestValidity.VALID : RequestValidity.INVALID));
  }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ //

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RowToMyWrapperObjCallable implements Callable<Stream<MyWrapperObj>> {

    private final List<Row> rows;
    private final RowConverter mapper;

    @Override
    public Stream<MyWrapperObj> call() throws Exception {
        log.info("Running mapping on thread: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return rows.stream().map(mapper);
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ //

@ApplicationScoped
public class RowConverter implements Function<Row, MyWrapperObj> {

  @Override
  public MyWrapperObj apply(Row row) {
    log.info("[{}] RowConverter::apply", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    // do the mapping
  }

}

So as you can see in my RowToMyWrapperObjCallable I do have a log for the thread name, and same in RowConverter. Those two however report different names. For example (with a custom thread pool, but same happens with the ManagedExecutorService:
2024-12-06 00:46:57.968+0200 INFO RowToMyWrapperObjCallable.call(Line 28) [pool-59-thread-1](523) [] Running mapping on thread: pool-59-thread-1
2024-12-06 00:46:57.968+0200 INFO RowToMyWrapperObjCallable.call(Line 28) [pool-59-thread-3](525) [] Running mapping on thread: pool-59-thread-3
2024-12-06 00:46:57.969+0200 INFO RowToMyWrapperObjCallable.call(Line 28) [pool-59-thread-4](526) [] Running mapping on thread: pool-59-thread-4
2024-12-06 00:46:57.968+0200 INFO RowToMyWrapperObjCallable.call(Line 28) [pool-59-thread-2](524) [] Running mapping on thread: pool-59-thread-2
2024-12-06 00:47:00.633+0200 INFO RowConverter.apply(Line 60) [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)](149) [] [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] RowConverter::apply
2024-12-06 00:47:00.889+0200 INFO RowConverter.apply(Line 60) [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)](149) [] [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] RowConverter::apply
2024-12-06 00:47:01.084+0200 INFO RowConverter.apply(Line 60) [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)](149) [] [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] RowConverter::apply

Anyone, has any ideas on why this might be happening and what I can do to make sure that my parallelism actually works?

Well apparently the problem here is in RowToMyWrapperObjCallable which returns a Stream. Since streams are lazily evaluated, the actual code will be executed when a terminal operator comes into play which takes place in BusinessService::process outside of the scope of ManagedExecutorService's context.
To resolve the issue, the only change needed is to materialize the stream into a collection (e.g. a List) and have RowToMyWrapperObjCallable return a List, something like this:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RowToMyWrapperObjCallable implements Callable<List<MyWrapperObj>> {

    private final List<Row> rows;
    private final RowConverter mapper;

    @Override
    public List<MyWrapperObj> call() throws Exception {
        log.info("Running mapping on thread: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return rows.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

PS: Morning clarity always helps...
